# Mozilla Thunderbird Tag Functionality

Tags: thunderbird

Does someone know where I can get documentation on the Mozilla Wiki or Mozilla Developer Network.  I mean the menu you get when you right-click a message and go to tag.  You see this.

1. Important
2. Work
3. Personal
4. To Do
5. Later

Specifically, I want to understand how it manipulates the email itself, not the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does http://kb.mozillazine.org/Tags this have anything to do with your question?  It looks like it adds a X-header to the message.

Comment: Somehow I missed that.  Probably because I decided to look at the the message headers in Thunderbird and not the raw MSF files in the profile folder. That wiki page also links to a [much more thorough explanation outside official resources based on a snapshot of the source code.](http://www.eyrich-net.org/mozilla/X-Mozilla-Status.html?en)